# Dead simple clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

What is a good clustering algorithm that simply puts two data items into the same cluster if their separation is less than some user specified cutoff?

i.e. the result of `X_clustering(data, distance, epsilon)` is a set of cluster assignments such that for any pair `i,j`, they are in the same cluster if `distance(data[i], data[j]) < epsilon`.  If `distance(data[i], data[j]) >= epsilon` they can be in different clusters (if there aren't other data that end up linking them...).

Another way of stating it is: `i,j` are in the same cluster if there exists a path `[i, x, y, z..., j]` through the data such that each step is of `distance<epsilon`, and they are in different clusters if no such path exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not working. If for all pairs of `(data[i], data[j])` in a cluster, their distance is less than a given `epsilon`, it means all members of that cluster are located in a circle with the radius of `epsilon`. Hence, this clustering method cannot be generalized.

By the way, DBSCAN is a good clustering algorithm in case of determining clusters base on their density with a given `epsilon`. You can modify this algorithm by adding a stronger constraint such that:

> each data can be added to a cluster if its distance to all members of the cluster is less than a given `epsilon`.